# yii2 ActiveDataProvider in combination with ActiveForm?

Tags: php, yii, yii2, cactivedataprovider

I'm trying to use an ActiveDataProvider as the source for my ActiveDataForm.
However I am unable to access the information. Not from within the view or the controller. How ever the  diseaseList + ListView is working.

I can't seem to figure out where I went wrong. Even when I get a disease like so:

```
$disease = new Disease();
$disease = Disease::find()->where(['id'=>1]);
```

I cannot access the data. Only when I initiate a NEW disease in the controller I can get the ActiveForm to work properly.

Controller:

```
public function actionIndex($id = 1)
{
    $disease = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => Disease::find()
        ->where(['id'=>$id]),
            'pagination' =>  [
                'pageSize' => 1,
            ]
        ]);
    
    $diseaseList = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => Disease::find()->orderBy('LOWER(name)'),
            'pagination' =>  [
                'pageSize' => 20,
            ]
        ]);
    return $this->render('index', ['disease' => $disease, 'diseaseList' => $diseaseList]);
}
```

In my view:

```
<?php 
echo ListView::widget([
'dataProvider' => $diseaseList,
'itemView' => function($diseaseList, $key, $index, $widget)
{
    return 
        Html::a($diseaseList->name,
            Url::toRoute(['disease/index', 'id' => $diseaseList->primaryKey]));
}
]); 
?>

<?php
    $form = ActiveForm::begin([
    'id' => 'disease-form-vertical'
    ]);
    ?>
        <?= $form->field($disease, 'name') ?>
        <?= $form->field($disease, 'description') ?>
        <?= $form->field($disease, 'transmission') ?>
        <?= $form->field($disease, 'actions') ?>
        <?= $form->field($disease, 'report') ?>
        <?= $form->field($disease, 'exclusion') ?>
        <?= $form->field($disease, 'notes') ?>
    <div class="form-group">
        <?= Html::submitButton('Login', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
        <?= Html::resetButton('Reset', ['class' => 'btn btn-default']) ?>
    </div>
    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

Here is the error I'm receiving.
[image: Error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is something wrong here, which is:

```
$disease = Disease::find()->where(['id'=>1]);
```

That should be:

```
$disease = Disease::find()->where(['id'=>1])->one();
```

To know why you get this error: You are passing `ActiveQuery` to your `ActiveForm` by `$disease = Disease::find()->where(['id'=>1])` which is wrong. `ActiveForm` does not accept `ActiveQuery`.

Comment: Thanks! Will try this in the morning!

Comment: This solved the problem. I also took the advice from my coleage to start reading the most significant elements of Yii2, he told me this whole question would not have existed if I'd done that before. Thanks for your help!